# Sharing whatsapp voice messages to my app android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to make the user using my app to be able to share voice messages sent in whatsapp to my app.
I've set this intent filter:

```
    <receiver android:name=".WhatsAppVoiceReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I've also set the following permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
```

But, when I try and share the voice message from whatsapp I'm not able to see my app appear on the list.

Help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.